# How to deals SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] error at plesk server?

Tags: laravel, plesk

I am new at plesk cpanel. I have tried to configure a laravel project on plesk for at least 5 hours. But It has showed the below error :

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'database_root'@'localhost' 
(using password: YES) (SQL: select * from `websites` limit 1)
```

I have searched on google and followed may articles . But can not fixed the errors. Please help me how to fix it.

**.env** file contains

```
DB_DATABASE=blog
DB_USERNAME=database_root
DB_PASSWORD=123456abc
```

Comment: `Access denied for user 'database_root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) ` has been asked (and answered) many times here before. Please do at least a basic search on the error message before asking a new question.

Comment: I did know . But I have followd most of the question and answer and applied to plesk server . But did not worl. That's why I have posted this question.

Answer (score 1):

**Check Database Credentials in cPanel**

**So next you need to reset your username and password. In cPanel, click on MySQL Databases under the Databases section.**

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=database name
DB_USERNAME=user name
DB_PASSWORD=your password
```

Comment: I have change it into 127.0.0.1 . But did not work.

Comment: please check your credential

Answer (score 1):

I think .env change doesn't appeared to that please clear your cache Make a route

```
Route::get('/clear', function() {

   Artisan::call('config:clear');
   Artisan::call('cache:clear'); 
   Artisan::call('view:clear');

   return "Cleared!";

});
```

Comment: proc_open(): CreateProcess failed, error code - 1260